# Change the quantity field in a cart to an unchangeable

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

how to make quantity field of items in the cart unchangeable.just display '1' but without update it.
i tried `

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

or

```
/app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use readonly attribute for quantity input field like below .It will not let user to chnage the qty.

```
        <input readonly = "readonly" type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
```

hope this will solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: it works now, I thought that doing this solution, block the input.
Now i put any number, it return it to "1". is well.

I want to know if you have an idea to add a notification when the user try to changes the field. i displays it a notification style: "You can select only one product" .staying on the same page.

Comment: but i don't think you can user can change the qty after this attribute , but you use jquery on-click  function to show alert on-click.  Please accept the answer if it is helpful to you .

Comment: look at the code below to show alert when user click on qty input.Thanks

Comment: Hello, could you tell me where exactly i should change the code to disable changing field because i realize now that it doesn't work any more.

Comment: you can place in footer the below code <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qty").click(function(){
alert('You can select only one product')        
    });
});

</script>

Comment: No not a function javascrpit , the <input readonly="readonly ..."> 
the path to a folder.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Place this code on product page. It will do your work if you have jquery in your project.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qty").click(function(){
alert('You can select only one product')        
    });
});

</script>
```